# Tags for seekbar in jsf primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using JSF Primefaces

I want to give a input type is seekbar need to increase the value up to 5.If we move seekbar cursor value needs to be increase upto 5 (Min value is 0, Max value is 5)

Can any one give me tags for seekbar

Answer (score 0):

Try the p:slider Tag.

[image: SLider Screenshot from Primefaces Showcase]

Check the Primefaces Showcase for examples how to use it: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/slider.xhtml

The Primefaces Showcase in general is very helpful to find the needed components: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/